# sql server architecture: switching database between read-only and read-write

Tags: sql-server-2008, switching, readonly

I have a database that is read-only in nature. So it seems to make sense to boost performance by setting it to readonly. Then I get updates for this database once a month. At that point I would like to switch to readwrite, do the updates, and switch back to readonly. I've looked around and haven't seen too much mention of this. Are there any problems I'm going to run into with this approach or is this as safe and basic as you get?

thanks

Comment: check this http://sql-server-performance.com/Community/forums/t/13244.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problems with this approach.

Remember to rebuild index and update stats before making it read only again.

Then again, keep it simple and read write always...?

Comment: Thanks gbn. Maybe I will keep it simple and not do that. Thought maybe it would give some performance advantages, but maybe they are not significant.

Comment: @Reggie: there is an advantage. It depends on load and size. Heavy use on a TB database=yes, do it....